# How to change the state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {User} from './components/User';
import {DefaultGame} from './components/DefaultGame';
import {EndGame} from './components/endGame';

class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            matchResults:undefined,
            gameStatus:undefined,

        };//end if state

    }//end of constructor

    startGame(event) {
        console.log('the game is starting');
        this.setState({
            gameStatus:true
        })
    }

    endGameUser(results) {
        console.log('clicked end Game', results);

        this.setState({
            gameStatus:false,
            matchResults:'hello'
        });

        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {



            if (this.state.gameStatus === true) {
                console.log('returning this');

                    return  (<User name={prompt('What is your name')} endGame={this.endGameUser.bind(this)} />)
            } else if (this.state.gameStatus === false) {
                return (
                    <EndGame userResultsWins='winnihn' />
                )
            } else {
                console.log('returning this not stating')
                    return (<DefaultGame startGameUser={(event) => this.startGame(event)}/>)

            }





    }
}//end of App component



ReactDOM.render(<Game/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {User} from './components/User';
import {DefaultGame} from './components/DefaultGame';
import {EndGame} from './components/endGame';

class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            matchResults:undefined,
            gameStatus:undefined,

        };//end if state

    }//end of constructor

    startGame(event) {
        console.log('the game is starting');
        this.setState({
            gameStatus:true
        })
    }

    endGameUser(results) {
        console.log('clicked end Game', results);

        this.setState({
            gameStatus:false,
            matchResults:'hello'
        });

        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {



            if (this.state.gameStatus === true) {
                console.log('returning this');

                    return  (<User name={prompt('What is your name')} endGame={this.endGameUser.bind(this)} />)
            } else if (this.state.gameStatus === false) {
                return (
                    <EndGame userResultsWins='winnihn' />
                )
            } else {
                console.log('returning this not stating')
                    return (<DefaultGame startGameUser={(event) => this.startGame(event)}/>)

            }





    }
}//end of App component



ReactDOM.render(<Game/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Hi, I am new to react and i made a simple game of rock paper scissors. I want to change the state of matchResults on the endGameUser function. I am able to change the state of gameStatus to false, but i can not change the state of matchResults. Right now i want toi change it to hello, but eventually i want to set it equal to an object. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state is being changed correctly but the problem is that you're checking the state before it's been updated.

Try moving your console.log to the callback.

```
this.setState({
    gameStatus:false,
    matchResults:'hello'
}, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setState`. Here are the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)!
The way you are currently using setState is actually correct but its not doing what you think it is doing. `setState` is asynchronous. So you can't call `setState` then right after see that this.state has changed. React batches setState calls until a certain time. The next time your render is called you will see that the state has changed. Move the console log to render and you will see this.

Comment: Thanks thats super helpful for this and future projects1